# C60 orbital calculation

Tags: matlab, visualization, quantum-mechanics

I am currently trying to reproduce [the results published by Hands et al.](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/97962.pdf)<sup>1</sup> using MATLAB. They calculated the bases of the C<sub>60</sub> wave functions of HOMO, LUMO and LUMO+1.

I did the following:

1. I implemented these functions into MATLAB syntax, e.g.

   `Tp1uxL5 = @(x,y,z) 35.*z.*(x.^4-6*x.^2.*y.^2+y.^4)-5*x.*(1-14*z.^2+21.*z.^4);
   Tp1uyL5 = @(x,y,z) 5*y.*(28.*z.^4-28*x.*z.*(x.^2-y.^2)-(1-7*z.^2).^2);
   Tp1uzL5 = @(x,y,z) 2*z.*(15-70*z.^2+63*z.^4)+7*x.*(5*(x.^2-y.^2).^2-4*x.^2);`

for the pentagon prone $T^p_{1ui} (L=5)$ (i=x,y,z) functions, multiplied by an exponential function $\exp(-k R)$ utilizing $k = \frac{Z_\text{eff}}{2} a_0$ with the effective charge $Z_\text{eff}=3.14$, the Bohr radius $a_0 = 52 \text{ pm}$, and $R = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ as proposed by the authors.

2. I normalized the functions by integrating in three dimensions using MATLAB's `integral3` function, i.e.

`A = integral3( FKT , -B,B , -B,B , -B,B )`

with the boundary $B$ which i varied between $0.5 \text{ nm} \le B \le 10 \text{ nm}$ with no change in result. I also tried just generating the 3D "wavefunction matrix" in those boundaries and taking the sum over all values.

3. I equated each base $T$ times exponential times normalization factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}$, squared for the propability amplitude, added the corresponding functions for the probability density $\Psi^2$ of HOMO, LUMO and LUMO+1 as well as pentagon, hexagon and double-bond prone configuration.
4. I generated plots:

   - A) "Constant height" STM images at $z=z_0$ by equating $\Psi^2 (x,y,z_0)$
   - B) "Constant current" STM images equating $\Psi^2 (x,y,z) = const.$ and visualizing the $z$ map.
   - C) 3D plots of the electron density (comparable to Fig. 4,6,8,11 in [1](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/97962.pdf)) by MATLABs `isosurface(X,Y,Z,DOS,DOSvalue)`.

Unfortunately, I fail to reproduce the pictures of [the report](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/97962.pdf). Below you see a calculated constant current image; constant height and the 3D probability density fronts show the same structure, so the visualization part of the code I guess is fine.

I checked and checked the functions again, I am starting to get mad over this. I am not reproducing the results of the paper. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**Fig. 1.** Simulated constant current images. First row: LUMO, second row: HOMO, third row: LUMO+1. First column: pentagone prone, second column: hexagone prone, third column double-bond prone.

View image [here](http://postimg.org/image/5ty7fu5rj/).

---

<sup>1</sup> "Calculation of images of oriented C<sub>60</sub> molecules using molecular orbital theory" Phys. Rev. B **81**, 205440 (2010), http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/97962.pdf

Comment: I think my visualization is fine, since I get the same structure in constant current, constant height as well as the 3D orbital plots. I guess that I make a systematic mistake in assuming the wave function form..

Comment: I think that you need to describe better your question. For example, you never mention in the text that they use [Hückel metho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method), as they write in the very first sentence of the paper. You can't just wait people to go an read the paper for you. You need to provide enough details, so they can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not too familiar with theoretical methods for calculating molecular orbitals or such, I assumed it is enough to start with the basis set they gave. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: You should start with understanding the method then. That should be done before to attempt to obtain reported results. Have you done it for simpler molecules? (H2 maybe?).

Comment: Than I probably should do that...

Comment: If this method is like others methods I know (Hartree-Fock, DFT, FEM). You need to expand your Operators in the proposed base and then solve for the eigenvalues/eigenvectors.